# Spring Mongo criteria problems with andOperator

Tags: spring, mongodb

I'm trying to create a dynamic mongoDB query using spring Criteria. My query is :

```
Criteria.where(key1).is(value1).and(key2).is(value2)
```

The numbers of key/value is not fixed but can change.

I try to use `andOperator` but it's not for my case.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 9):

This post explains a similara problem:
[Spring Mongo criteria querying twice the same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698689/spring-mongo-criteria-querying-twice-the-same-field)

This is what you want to do:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(
                                    Criteria.where("key1").is(value1),  
                                    Criteria.where("key2").is(value2));
// to print the mongodb query for debug purposes
// System.out.println(criteria.getCriteriaObject());

// execute with a mongoTemplate
List<YourClass> documents = mongoTemplate.find(new Query(criteria), YourClass.class);
```